# function was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int information1(int hourR);
int information2(int conTime);
int intformation3(int income1);
int hourR,conTime,income1;
ofstream outfile;

int main()
{
    int hours,consultTime,income,fortyPercent,seventyPercent;
    outfile.open("Billing amount.txt");
    hours=information1(hourR);
    consultTime=information2(conTime);
    income=information3(income1);

    if((income<=25000)&&(consultTime<=30))
    {
        outfile<<"No charges";
    }
    else if((income>=25000)&&(consultTime>=30))
    {
        fortyPercent=hours*.4;
        outfile<<fortyPercent;
    }

    if(consultTime<=20)
    {
        outfile<<"No charges";
    }
    else if(consultTime>20)
    {
        seventyPercent=hours*.7;
        outfile<<seventyPercent;
    }

    outfile.close();
    return 0;
}

int information1(int hourR)
{
    cout<<"Enter hourly rate.";
    cin>>hourR;
    return hourR;
}

int information2(int conTime)
{
    cout<<"Enter total consulting time";
    cin>>conTime;
    return conTime;
}

int intformation3(int income1)
{
    cout<<"Enter income.";
    cin>>income1;
    return income1;
}
```

The compiler says information3 is not declared in this scope.  But when I do declare it, the compiler says I cant use it. There might be more problems with this program but as of now I'm stuck on this part. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Typo: `intformation3` vs. `information3`.

Comment: ...and when you're done with that, *please* learn to indent your code.

Comment: Don't paraphrase compiler messages, post them verbatim.

Answer (score 4):

spot the difference

```
int intformation3(int income1);
      ^

income=information3(income1);
```